# Why can we let $u(x_1,x_2=0)=u_0(x_1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, multivariable-calculus

> Say I have a function $u:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$,  given by $u(x_1,x_2)$.
>
> At $x_2=0$ let
>
> $$
> u(x_1,0)=u_0(x_1)
> $$

Intuitively, I understand this is right but why is it mathematically correct?

Can we always introduce a new function this way?

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_0: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a function that sends $x_1$ to $u(x_1,0)$, i.e. $x_1 \mapsto u(x_1,0)$.